# Polars: Enforcing dtypes doesn't work why?

Tags: python, date, datetime, casting, python-polars

Why schema specification has no impact? Date of Birth continues to be in string format why?

```
import polars as pl

# Create a dictionary with some dummy data
data = {
    'Age': [28, 32, 24, 45, 29],
    'Date of Birth': ['1995-03-15', '1989-08-22', '1999-11-05', '1978-02-10', '1994-06-07'],
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Sydney'],
}

dtypes = {
    'Age': pl.Int64,
    'Date of Birth': pl.Date,
    'City': pl.Utf8
}

# Create the DataFrame with specified data types
df_listing_data = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=dtypes)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving it date objects, you're giving it a list of strings. It's not going to guess at how to parse them. I'm actually surprised it doesn't raise an error for giving it data that doesn't meet your specified dtypes. I would say that's a [bug](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9634) but the resolution of the bug is that you'd get an error instead of a df with the wrong dtype. To get dates you either need to give it a list of date objects or tell it how to parse your strings into dates after the df is created or give it a Series that is of type date.

You can do

```
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'Age': [28, 32, 24, 45, 29],
    'Date of Birth': [datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for x in ['1995-03-15', '1989-08-22', '1999-11-05', '1978-02-10', '1994-06-07']],
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Sydney'],
}

dtypes = {
    'Age': pl.Int64,
    'Date of Birth': pl.Date,
    'City': pl.Utf8
}

# Create the DataFrame with specified data types
df_listing_data = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=dtypes)
```

OR

```
data = {
    'Age': [28, 32, 24, 45, 29],
    'Date of Birth': ['1995-03-15', '1989-08-22', '1999-11-05', '1978-02-10', '1994-06-07'],
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Sydney'],
}

dtypes = {
    'Age': pl.Int64,
    'Date of Birth': pl.Date,
    'City': pl.Utf8
}

# Create the DataFrame with specified data types
df_listing_data = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=dtypes).with_columns(
    pl.col('Date of Birth').str.strptime(pl.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

OR

```
data = {
    'Age': [28, 32, 24, 45, 29],
    'Date of Birth': pl.Series(['1995-03-15', '1989-08-22', '1999-11-05', '1978-02-10', '1994-06-07']).str.strptime(pl.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d"),
    'City': ['New York', 'San Francisco', 'London', 'Tokyo', 'Sydney'],
}

dtypes = {
    'Age': pl.Int64,
    'Date of Birth': pl.Date,
    'City': pl.Utf8
}

# Create the DataFrame with specified data types
df_listing_data = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=dtypes)
```

Comment: IIUC that misses the point; if you set e.g. `'Age': pl.Float32`, type casting works fine. The usage of `schema` is described like this in [the docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html).

Comment: @FObersteiner but you can't cast a string to a date or datetime, you can only strptime it.

Comment: if you're reading a csv you can use `try_parse_dates` but if you're giving it python objects to create the df it expects the types to match.

Comment: of course, for "casting" you'd have to infer the format with all the caveats that come with that etc. etc. BUT: if polars allows to set date/datetime/time type in a schema, then IMHO this should either work or fail, not silently do nothing.

Comment: I agree that it shouldn't silently do nothing, I said I'm surprised it doesn't raise an error.

Comment: ok it *does* give an error for `pl.Datetime`; but this one isn't very meaningful imho :)

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9634

Comment: Why it can't infer string to date on declaring? Shouldn't it be same as when reading from csv with try_parse_dates enabled?

Comment: @rram "why?" I guess because nobody built that in yet. I added that idea to the above issue.

Comment: It’s quite different to CSV; if you’re passing values into a DataFrame on init then you have complete control over those values - you could choose to convert them to the correct type yourself (without guessing, since you presumably know the format), or simply pass then in as strings and then immediately apply a strptime expression - and, again, this should be efficient as you can provide the exact format. With a CSV everything starts as a string and every value _has_ to be converted. In the next release you’ll now get a sensible error suggesting use of strptime in this case.